# js import not finding wasm file

Tags: javascript, node.js, rust, webassembly

I'm striving to build following example of wasm from rust :

[example](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/tree/master/examples/dom)

I've executed

> cargo build

and it resolved with libdom.d and libdom.so files in target/debug/ file.

Application starts with given

> npm run serve

but it throws error when js tries to import wasm file on line:

> import('./pkg/dom')

resulting with

```
> @ serve /home/kamil/projects/dom
> webpack-dev-server

  Checking for wasm-pack...

ℹ️  Installing wasm-pack 

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /home/kamil/projects/dom
ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
wasm-pack error: undefined
✖ ｢wdm｣: Hash: d6af309c4a2560e4a081
Version: webpack 4.36.1
Time: 21666ms
Built at: 07/18/2019 6:53:10 PM
     Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
index.html  226 bytes          [emitted]  
  index.js    360 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = index.js
[0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost ./index.js 40 bytes {main} [built]
[./index.js] 133 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/ansi-html/index.js] 4.16 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js] 135 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/html-entities/index.js] 231 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js] 7.68 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] 161 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost 4.29 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.51 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.53 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js 2.77 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/log.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/log.js 964 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js 1.63 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/sendMessage.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/sendMessage.js 402 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {main} [built]
    + 18 hidden modules

ERROR in ./index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './pkg/dom' in '/home/kamil/projects/dom'
 @ ./index.js 3:0-19
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./index.html] 372 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 528 KiB {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

There is no `./pkg/dom` folder. I don't know how to generate it, or what should be in it.

Comment: Does the pkg/dom file exist?

Comment: No. Forgot to mention that. I don't know how to generate it, or what should be in it.

Comment: Did you download everything in the dom example folder? I just did, ran `yarn` and then `yarn serve` and it works correctly as well as generates the pkg folder and file.

Comment: Yes, I have everything. Why did you use yarn? I'm not familiar with it. I thought cargo will be enough to build this.

Comment: I've tried this approach with yarn (on clean pull). The result is still the same.

Comment: I prefer yarn, it isn't required. But you shouldn't need to call cargo at all -- wasm-pack will build the rust code for you.  You could call cargo to generate the wasm file but then you would have to manually create the js file that creates the wasm heap.

Comment: Also what version of node and rustc are you using?

Comment: ```rustc 1.35.0 (3c235d560 2019-05-20)```
node ```v11.15.0```

Comment: kyle, what this generated folder contains?

Comment: since you're using wasm-pack try running `wasm-pack build` instead of `cargo build`, it's what generates the ./pkg folder. You have a `wasm-pack error: undefined` error...

Answer (score 1):

The index.js file is trying to `import('./pkg')` which doesn't exist.  You generate this folder by running `wasm-pack build`.  After doing so, you should have a `./pkg` folder which contains the wasm binary and JS wrapper code.  See the [wasm-pack README](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack#%EF%B8%8F-commands) for more information on commands.

Playing with Rust, it is tempting to just call `cargo build` and expect it to create the wasm binary, however wasm-pack is actually [doing a lot more](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack/blob/master/src/command/build.rs#L177) under the hood.  Ultimately though, `wasm-pack build` does call [cargo build](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack/blob/master/src/build/mod.rs#L119).